# Limitations and strength of Xbap and Wpf applications

Tags: wpf, xbap

I am about to start a new application. I am bit confused on deciding on wpf or xbap application. I need a list of limitations and advantages of Xbap and Wpf independently. 
Looking into these pros/cons, and my requirements, I can take a call.

Answer (score 1):

Xbap applications are Wpf applications that can be deployed through a browser (IE or Firefox). Xbaps must run under partial-trust, so there are some limitations on what you can do (you can't open child windows for example). Here's an [overview of what XBaps are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx).

These days you probably want to also consider Silverlight, which is essentially a subset of Wpf, but with very much smaller download footprint (WPF is between 30 - 300 Mb, Silverlight, IIRC is about 4Mb). The decision between WPF vs Xbap vs Silverlight is discussed further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160770/wpf-vs-xbap-vs-silverlight-which-suits-business-applications).

Answer (score 0):

XBAPs can also run in Full Thrust with some configuration.