# Silverlight 5 - comprehensive list of improvements/changes

Tags: silverlight

Is there comprehensive list of what's new in silverlight 5? I'm seeing different blogs, etc but obviously the devil is in details.

When they say better binding support what exactly different better? And so on.. I'd like to see detailed paper..

Comment: Ignoring blogs, I think the Silverlight.net site is the best place to start: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/what's-new-in-silverlight-5 Among other things it has this paper on the new features: http://i1.silverlight.net/content/downloads/silverlight_5_beta_features.pdf?cdn_id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pete Brown has a list of the major changes in the RC.

http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/04/the-big-list-of-whats-new-or-improved-in-silverlight-5

Answer (score 1):

Besides SO, I usually find the best detail covered in the MSDN Library.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=silverlight+5&ac=8