# WPF Browser Applications vs WPF Desktop Applications

Tags: wpf, xaml, browser, desktop, xbap

I want to know what are the differences between a **WPF Browser Application** and **WPF Desktop Application**. I know that the browser application runs on IE and FF, but about the technology, is the same? I mean, we can do exactly the same by the two ways? (Of course, maybe with different UI)

I have this doubt because I'm looking for a book about WPF Browser Applications, but I only see books about WPF (I don't know if is in general or is only for desktop applications :S)

Comment: Although being a little biased to Silverlight, this discussion may also help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160770/wpf-vs-xbap-vs-silverlight-which-suits-business-applications

Answer (score 4):

A WPF Browser Application uses exactly the same framework as a WPF desktop application and could run with the same UI, but with restrictions on trust which means that some APIs are not available. There a number of challenges in developing Browser application.   A Browser app must be signed with a certificate. Some of the trust restrictions are not enforced at compile time and are only discovered at run time.

In the time since Browser Applications were first introduced, Microsoft developed Silverlight which uses a similar though not identical XAML technology. Silverlight is easier to deploy than a WPF Browser Application and may be appropriate depending upon your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A Browser Application not only runs in the browser but also with less authority.  If you need to read and write local files then go WPF.   Browser is good is you want rapid deployment to lots of PCs.  Other wise I will take WPF Desktop every time.  Most WPF books with have a chapter on XBAP.  I like McDonald from Apress.

Comment: How do I debug a failure of the component in WPF browser App which runs fine with a full WPF app?