# Are there any WPF-XBAP Applications in the wild?

Tags: wpf, xbap

Do you know any WPF XAML Browser Applications?

Commercial or open source.

Thanks

Comment: Can't imagine there are too many due to the limitations they have. How about [Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160770/wpf-vs-xbap-vs-silverlight-which-suits-business-applications)?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Actipro web [demo](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/download/demos) count?